# Stealing and reattaching a running process

Tags: ssh, r, disown

It's sunday and I left an instance of R running in the office. The script finished running, and I would like to save my workspace without going to the office. I can ssh to the computer, but I have not run the program into screen.

Is there a way, over ssh, to disown the process (I don't have access to jobsid of the terminal the program is running on!) and reattach it with say, reptyr? Reptyr and reptyr -T don't work without previously disowning the process

```
28845 3diag       20   0  139.3m  10.4m   0.0  0.1   0:12.06 S  `- urxvtd                                                                                      
 5327 3diag       20   0   16.4m   4.6m   0.0  0.1   0:00.02 S      `- bash                                                                                    
 5335 3diag       20   0 3499.3m 3.244g   0.0 43.3 171:57.89 S          `- R
```

The unique part of my question is that I explicitly require to detach a program without having access to the terminal in which it was created.

Comment: the `reptyr` man page does not say you *have* to disown the process first. It says you may want to.

Comment: Still, I get an error when I try that

Comment: reptyr 28845
[-] Process 28828 (xmonad-x86_64-l) shares 28845's process group. Unable to attach.
(This most commonly means that 28845 has suprocesses).
Unable to attach to pid 28845: Invalid argument

Similarly:
reptyr -T 28845
[-] Child is not connected to a pseudo-TTY. Unable to steal TTY.
Unable to attach to pid 28845: Invalid argument

Comment: similarly, if I try with the child process (which is the one I want to actually get to)

reptyr 5335
Unable to attach to pid 5335: Operation not permitted
The kernel denied permission while attaching. If your uid matches
the target's, check the value of /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope.
For more information, see /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf

Comment: Don't try to attach to `urxvtd`, it's just a daemon. Did you look into the files mentioned by the second invocation? Please update the post instead of commenting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Invocation of `reptyr` is sufficient to detach the terminal, but has to be

```
sudo reptyr -T $PID
```

From `man reptyr`:

> -T
>
> Use an alternate mode of attaching, "TTY-stealing".
>
> In this mode, reptyr will not ptrace(2) the target process, but will attempt to discover he terminal emulator for that process' pty, and steal the master end of the pty.
>
> This mode is more reliable and flexible  in many  circumstances (for instance, it can attach all processes on a tty, rather than just a single process).
>
> However, as a downside, children of sshd(8) cannot be attached via -T unless reptyr is run as root.  See 
>   ⟨https://blog.nelhage.com/2014/08/new-reptyr-feature-tty-stealing/⟩ 
>   for more information about tty-stealing.